# TYPO3 and IOS: can't open the page

Tags: php, ios, .htaccess, safari, typo3

My situation:
I have 10 typo3-websites running on two servers:

- First Server (apache with php 5.6.32):

  - typo3 versions: 6.2.3, 6.2.4 and 6.2.14
- Second Server (apache with php 7.0.26):

  - typo3 versions: 7.6.14 and 8.7.1.

---

- I'm not able to open the page on an iPhone or iPad with osx 10.x or above. I tested it on safari, chrome and firefox, but I get always an error like:
  "[browser] can't open the page (...) because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection. (...)"
- On a mac (osx 10), I get the error only in safari 11.0.2, but not in firefox or chrome.
- I can open the pages without any problems, if I'm logged in at the typo3-backend with the same browser.
- A Wordpress-Page is also running on the second server without any problems.
- I have no problems on windows, android or other linux machines.

---

I tried the following without success:

- clearing the typo3 cache
- using the default .htaccess
- using an empty .htaccess
- The solutions from this site (german!): http://www.typo3forum.net/discussion/79617/ios-10-3-1-laedt-seite-nicht

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to set the header content-length to 0?
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#enablecontentlengthheader

Try to set the following lines to your TypoScript

```
config.enableContentLengthHeader = 0
```

You say you can open the page if you are logged in that matches the following description:

> If the Backend user is logged in, this is disabled. The reason is that
>   the content length header cannot include the length of these objects
>   and the content-length will cut off the length of the document in some
>   browsers.

Comment: Is this a workaround for a known bug? Can you provide a link?